# jQuery drag, drop, clone and sort - Elements working separetly not together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, clone

I'm a little new to working with jQuery in this manner so please be patient with me. I searched for an answer to my question, but didn't see what I was looking likely because I was not searching the correct terms. So this is my problem.

I have 2 divs side by side. In the left div I have buttons that I'm dragging into the right div. I have pre defined animations set in my css that I want to fire in the right column, while leaving a clone of the draggable buttons in the left. My animations are working fine, but instead of leaving a clone in the left column it's cloning my buttons in the right on top of my animations. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here. Here is the code I've been working with.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="hide-overflow">
            <ul id="all-colls-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable">
                <li id="music" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-music.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="nav" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-nav.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="climate" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-seats.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="phone" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-phone.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="weather" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-weather.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="email" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-email.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="calendar" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-calendar.svg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="sortable" class="stage ui-state-highlight">
                <div id="frame">
                    <ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lists = [{
        "listid": "#all-colls-list",
        "connectid": "#coll-selected-list"
    }, {
        "listid": "#coll-selected-list",
        "connectid": "#all-colls-list"
    }];
$.each(lists, function(i, list) {
    $(list.listid).sortable({
        connectWith: list.connectid,
        opacity: 0.7,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).addClass('dropped');
            }

            else {
                $(ui.item).addClass('sorted');
            }
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('dropped', 'sortedli');
            }
            else if ($("#music").addClass('droppedmusic').length > 1) {;
                                                                      }
            else if ($("#nav").addClass('droppednav').length > 1) {
            }
            else if ($("#climate").addClass('droppedclimate').length > 1) {
            } 
            else if ($("#phone").addClass('droppedphone').length > 1) {
            }
            else if ($("#weather").addClass('droppedweather').length > 1) {
            }
            else if ($("#email").addClass('droppedemail').length > 1) {
            }
            else if ($("#calendar").addClass('droppedlicalendar').length > 1) {
            }
            else {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('sortedli', 'droppedli');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

#all-colls-list{
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
}

#coll-selected-list{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    height: 480px;
}


img. {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
} 

#coll-selected-list li{
    background: #2d2d2d;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 
    animation-duration: 1.0s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.0s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#all-colls-list-map li, #coll-selected-list li{
    list-style:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dropped {
    height: auto;
}

.droppedclimate{
    height: 104px;
    background-image: url('img/climate-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppednav{
    height: 81px;
    background-image: url('img/map-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedweather{
    height: 143px;
    background-image: url('img/weather-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedphone{
    height: 110px;
    background-image: url('img/phone-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedmusic{
    height: 168px;
    background-image: url('img/no-clue-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedlicalendar{
    height: 158px;
    background-image: url('img/calendar-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedemail{
    height: 121px;
    background-image: url('img/email-sm.png') !important;
}

#all-colls-list li:hover, #coll-selected-list li:hover{
    cursor: move;
}

#hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 455px;  
}

.sorted{
    background-color:#a74455;
}

.sortedli{
    background: none !important;
}   

.none {
    visibility: hidden !important;  
}
.droppedmusicbg{
    background-image: url('img/icon-music.png'); 
}
</style>
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are the 2 parts of the puzzle working separately. I'm trying to make them work together in 1 iteration.Clone Nav and Drag (http://jsfiddle.net/natebalcom/m51ywh7g/) Drag, Drop, Sortable (http://jsfiddle.net/natebalcom/sorgm2Lz/)

Comment: This is where I found my drag, drop and clone code --> [link](http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/) The problem is the drag, drop and clone code doesn't want to play with the sortable code.